# Faceted Search - Using multiple facets with AND / OR conjunction

Tags: solr, drupal-8, facet, faceted-search

I am using `Solr 8.7.0` with `Drupal 8`. I have multiple solr facets in place but need to set up OR condition for some facets and also AND conditions with some facets. Example as below:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Brand       | Colour      | Price          |
| [] ABC      | [] Blue     | [.] 10 - 100   |
| [] DEF      | [] Green    | [] 101 - 200   |
| [.] GHI     | [.] Yellow  | [] 201 - 300   |
| [] JKL      | [] Black    | [] 301 - 400   |
----------------------------------------------
```

So the need is to get the **Brand union Colour intersection Price**. Show all the products which are tagged under Brand GHI or Colour Yellow but within price range 10 - 100.

Please note: Brand/Colour/Price are three separate facets. What options (either Drupal or Apache Solr) do we have to achieve this ?

Comment: Index a separate field that is the combination of Brand and Color: `Brand_Color:"GHI|Yellow"` and facet on that field.

Comment: Yes I came across a similar solution where it speaks about combining facets. https://www.keboca.com/drupal-8-merge-facets-together - I will write about it once able to accomplish that.